# C++ pointer gets overwritten in for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, pointers, memory-management

Could someone explain why pointers gets overwritten when variables are declared inside a loop?

For example, given the following snippet, and the user inputs 1 and 2. I would expect that the `pNums` array contain 2 pointers to 2 integers holding the value 1 and 2 respectively.

But instead, the console prints out `2` and `2`;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Input "1 2"
int main() {
    int* pNums[2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        int num;
        cin >> num;
        pNums[i] = (&num);
    }
    cout << (*pNums[0]) << endl;
    cout << (*pNums[1]) << endl; 
}
```

Why is this the case? And how do I get around it? What if, for example, we don't know how many numbers the user will put in, and instead of a `for` loop, we have a `while` loop? Until some conditions are met, we want to keep creating new pointers and store them into a `pNums` vector?

Comment: The int variable is actually declared just the once for all for loop iterations and thus shares the same memory.  You Want to look at dynamic variables and using new / delete. Or change to using another approach like a std::vector list where you can add numbers to the list.

Comment: Why do you want to keep creating new *pointers*? Don't you want new *values*? What's the purpose of creating new pointers if there aren't any new things for them to point to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one `num`, and you are overwriting *that.* (And then causing Undefined Behavior, but never mind that.)

There are two simple ways to avoid this mistake.

1) Store objects, not pointers:

```
int nums[2];
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    cin >> nums[i];
}
```

2) Use dynamic allocation:

```
int* pNums[2];
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    int *p=new int;
    cin >> *p;
    pNums[i] = p;
}
```

Comment: But remember to delete the data you declared to avoid memory leaks. Or use smart pointers.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle If we use dynamic allocation, when/how do I delete the data? And what are smart pointers? Could you please point me to a tutorial or documentation if it's too long to explain here?

Comment: @Synia See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/new-and-delete-operators-in-cpp-for-dynamic-memory/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=vs-2019. A good tutorial will explain these approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    int num; //< this is num. It lives here.
    cin >> num; 
    pNums[i] = (&num);  //< you have taken the address of num (twice!)
}
// here is when 'num' is destroyed (no longer in scope)

// so this is now pointing at something that doesn't exist. 
cout << (*pNums[0]) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The pointers that you are storing in `pNums` are to two instances of the variable `num` in the `for` block. There is one instance of the variable in each `for` loop iteration and these variables live only until the end of their respective iteration of the `for` loop body is reached.

Therefore your pointers will be invalid when the `for` loop exits and so trying to dereference them with e.g. `*pNums[0]` causes [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Don't store pointer, store values:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Input "1 2"
int main() {
    int pNums[2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        int num;
        cin >> num;
        pNums[i] = num;
    }
    cout << pNums[0] << endl;
    cout << pNums[1] << endl; 
}
```

and if you need a variable number of entries in the array, use `std::vector`.